# How to set multiple spans on a TextView's text (clickable and bold)

Tags: android, spannablestring

```
    mSpannableString = new SpannableString("12:00PM");

    mSpannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 7, 0);
    mSpannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(mSpannableString);

    mCancelFrom.setText(getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " " + mSpannableString);
```

i need to set the text to bold and make it clickable. the above code i have written in a dialog. the string "12:00PM" is getting displayed. but there is not bold effect on it and it is not clickable. can you hel me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This ,it may be help to you

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("12:00PM");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SendSMS.this, SendSMS.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mCancelFrom.setText(getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " " + ss);
```

Comment: how to make it the text bold?

Comment: ok,show updated answer add this line `ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Still there is no change it.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute
*mCancelFrom.setText(getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " " + mSpannableString);*

which executes:
*getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " " + mSpannableString*

The result of the above operation is a "String" therefore framework calls mSpannableString.toString to be able to append the previous two strings and you lose your spans etc.

Something like this (this is almost exactly your code):

```
String tmp = getString(R.string.cancel_from_text) + " ";
mSpannableString = new SpannableString(tmp + "12:00PM");

mSpannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, tmp.length(), mSpannableString.length(), 0);
mSpannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), tmp.length(), mSpannableString.length(), 0);

TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(mSpannableString);
```